# Optimization techniques for Flex applications

Tags: performance, apache-flex, flex4

We are starting to build a **Flex 4.5** application (with **LCDS**) and a **Spring/Hibernate** based backend.

In this context, is there a well-known list of overall performance optimization techniques that one could follow to ensure optimal performance on the client (flex) side? - especially, given that we anticipate users with poor bandwidths.

This could really be a checklist that we can start off with, and try to address one by one.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of performance is really relative; so there is no single definitive list.  A lot of things you can do to optimize performance on the Flex side are completely independent of any server side technology.

However, I'll start out with one suggestion.

Make sure to use AMF as your data transfer protocol.  When compared to REST or SOAP data transfer, AMF is a binary format and will result in a much smaller packet size being shifted back and forth.  Also AMF allows for automatic translation of server side object to client side object.  This can be a big time saver in development time (and I've been told processing time), because you don't have to deal with writing code to manually parse the XML.

Comment: I'd also like to add that most of the projects I've consulted on, their main problem area is data architecture (ie. sending too much data that isn't needed just yet or not reusing data properly).  Creating a proper data model on the server side and not just doing an SQL dump is very important for optimizing your app.